# nesting of BottomtabNavigator and DrawerNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-drawer

I have been trying to nest BottomTabNavigator and DrawerNavigator but has been unable to do so. I have written the code for drawer navigator in my App.js and has imported components **Passenger** from Passenger.js and **Lovedones** from lovedones.js. These two components contain the same code of bottomtabnavigator so that my bottomtabnavigator appears in all the screens of drawernavigator. If I individually run the code for bottomtabnavigator, it works perfectly.

the error that I am getting is-

Looks like you have nested a 'NavigationContainer' inside another. Normally you need only one container at the root of the app, so this was probably an error. If this was intentional, pass 'independent={true}' explicitely. Note that this will make the child navigators disconnected from the parent and you won't be able to navigate between them.

I have mentioned my code-

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';


import Passenger from './Passenger';
import Lovedones from './Lovedones';


import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default App=() => (
<NavigationContainer>
    <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Passenger">
        <Drawer.Screen name="Passenger" component={Passenger} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Lovedones" component={Lovedones} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
);
```

**Passenger.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';


import MapsScreen from './MapScreen';
import Driver from './Driver';
import Emergency from './EmergencyScreen';
import Account from './AccountScreen';

import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default Passenger=() => (
  <NavigationContainer>
    <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Map"  tabBarOptions={{ activeTintColor: '#e91e63', }}>
      <Tab.Screen name="Account" component={Account} options={{ tabBarLabel: 'Account', tabBarIcon: ({ color, size}) => (<MaterialCommunityIcons name="account-box" color={"#000000"} size={30} />), }}/>
      <Tab.Screen name="Driver" component={Driver} options={{ tabBarLabel: 'Driver Details', tabBarIcon: ({ color, size}) => (<MaterialCommunityIcons name="card-account-details" color={"#000000"} size={30} />), }}/>
      <Tab.Screen name="Map" component={MapsScreen} options={{ tabBarLabel: 'Map', tabBarIcon: ({ color, size}) => (<MaterialCommunityIcons name="map-marker" color={"#0000FF"} size={30} />), }}/>
      <Tab.Screen name="Emergency" component={Emergency} options={{ tabBarLabel: 'Emergency', tabBarIcon: ({ color, size}) => (<MaterialCommunityIcons name="alarm-light" color={"#FF0000"} size={30} />), }}/>
      
    </Tab.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
);
```

**Lovedones.js**

```
 import React from 'react';
    import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
    import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
    
    import MapsScreen from './MapScreen';
    import Driver from './Driver';
    import Emergency from './EmergencyScreen';
    import Account from './AccountScreen';
    
    import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
    const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
    
    export default Passenger=() => (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Map"  tabBarOptions={{ activeTintColor: '#e91e63', }}>
          <Tab.Screen name="Account" component={Account} options={{ tabBarLabel: 'Account', tabBarIcon: ({ color, size}) => (<MaterialCommunityIcons name="account-box" color={"#000000"} size={30} />), }}/>
          <Tab.Screen name="Driver" component={Driver} options={{ tabBarLabel: 'Driver Details', tabBarIcon: ({ color, size}) => (<MaterialCommunityIcons name="card-account-details" color={"#000000"} size={30} />), }}/>
          <Tab.Screen name="Map" component={MapsScreen} options={{ tabBarLabel: 'Map', tabBarIcon: ({ color, size}) => (<MaterialCommunityIcons name="map-marker" color={"#0000FF"} size={30} />), }}/>
          <Tab.Screen name="Emergency" component={Emergency} options={{ tabBarLabel: 'Emergency', tabBarIcon: ({ color, size}) => (<MaterialCommunityIcons name="alarm-light" color={"#FF0000"} size={30} />), }}/>
          
        </Tab.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
```

Kindly help me out in identifying the error

Comment: Keep the navigation container in the root navigator and remove it from others

Comment: thanks a lot sir. Since I am a beginner, can u elaborate your solution? It will help me in implementing your solution. I am unable to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

remove the extra NavigationContainer from Passenger.js and LovedOnes.js:

Passenger.js

```
export default Passenger=() => (
    <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Map"  tabBarOptions={{ activeTintColor: '#e91e63', }}>
      <Tab.Screen name="Account" component={Account} options={{ tabBarLabel: 'Account', tabBarIcon: ({ color, size}) => (<MaterialCommunityIcons name="account-box" color={"#000000"} size={30} />), }}/>
      <Tab.Screen name="Driver" component={Driver} options={{ tabBarLabel: 'Driver Details', tabBarIcon: ({ color, size}) => (<MaterialCommunityIcons name="card-account-details" color={"#000000"} size={30} />), }}/>
      <Tab.Screen name="Map" component={MapsScreen} options={{ tabBarLabel: 'Map', tabBarIcon: ({ color, size}) => (<MaterialCommunityIcons name="map-marker" color={"#0000FF"} size={30} />), }}/>
      <Tab.Screen name="Emergency" component={Emergency} options={{ tabBarLabel: 'Emergency', tabBarIcon: ({ color, size}) => (<MaterialCommunityIcons name="alarm-light" color={"#FF0000"} size={30} />), }}/>
      
    </Tab.Navigator>
);
```

LovedOnes.js

```
export default Passenger=() => (
    <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Map"  tabBarOptions={{ activeTintColor: '#e91e63', }}>
      <Tab.Screen name="Account" component={Account} options={{ tabBarLabel: 'Account', tabBarIcon: ({ color, size}) => (<MaterialCommunityIcons name="account-box" color={"#000000"} size={30} />), }}/>
      <Tab.Screen name="Driver" component={Driver} options={{ tabBarLabel: 'Driver Details', tabBarIcon: ({ color, size}) => (<MaterialCommunityIcons name="card-account-details" color={"#000000"} size={30} />), }}/>
      <Tab.Screen name="Map" component={MapsScreen} options={{ tabBarLabel: 'Map', tabBarIcon: ({ color, size}) => (<MaterialCommunityIcons name="map-marker" color={"#0000FF"} size={30} />), }}/>
      <Tab.Screen name="Emergency" component={Emergency} options={{ tabBarLabel: 'Emergency', tabBarIcon: ({ color, size}) => (<MaterialCommunityIcons name="alarm-light" color={"#FF0000"} size={30} />), }}/>
      
    </Tab.Navigator>
);
```